# remove focus from a button which was clicked

Tags: c++, winapi

When I click a button the focus is set to this button.

How do I remove the focus from this button with WIN API in C++?

I think maybe somehow with the `SendMessage` WIN API method it is possible to remove the focus from the button.

I have only the handle of button, also I cannot access the parent window anymore.

I know that almost everytime it is possible to use `::SetFocus`, but this time I cannot use it since I cannot access the window form even if I find the handle. So please suggest other solutions.

Comment: What do you want to be in focus after? `SetFocus` is probably what you want.

Comment: Why can't you call [`GetParent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633510.aspx)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply put the focus on another window by calling `::SetFocus` (or `CWnd::SetFocus` if you are using MFC) with the desired window's handle/pointer.

Comment: but what if i cannot access anymore the parent form window ? i cannot access, please advice other thing. Thanks

Comment: What do you mean you cannot access it?  If you have access to the child window, you have access to the parent (via `::GetParent` or `CWnd::GetParent`).

Comment: ::SetFocus((HWND)GetParent()) may not work for button

Answer (score 3):

You can put focus on another window, but if you really don't need to have focus. it is better to use `::SetFocus(NULL)`. This way prevent some windows messages to be sent, as a result performance may be very slightly increased.

Comment: This is the best solution that does the job with minimum of code. Also you need to remeber that ::SetSocus( hWnd ) may not succeed but NULL always works.

Answer (score 1):

Subclass the button and interface the `WM_SETFOCUS` message.  That will tell you the `HWND` that is losing focus.  You can then `SetFocus()` back to that `HWND` if needed.