# How to remove border focus (dots rectangle) after clicking on CMFCButton?

Tags: c++, mfc

How to remove border focus (dots rectangle) after click on CMFCButton?
Here is my code to create button.

```
CMFCButton btn_Phone.ModifyStyle(0, BS_ICON);
btn_Phone.m_nFlatStyle = CMFCButton::BUTTONSTYLE_NOBORDERS;
HICON hIcnPhone = (HICON)LoadImage(
    AfxGetApp()->m_hInstance,
    MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_PHONE),
    IMAGE_ICON,
    17, 17,
    LR_DEFAULTCOLOR
);
btn_Phone.SetIcon(hIcnPhone);
```

This: [image]

Comment: Maybe this SO article helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18539832/remove-focus-from-a-button-which-was-clicked

Comment: Or try to send the somewhat obscure [WM_UPDATEUISTATE](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-ch/windows/desktop/menurc/wm-updateuistate) message to the window containing the `btn_Phone` button: `SendMessage(WM_UPDATEUISTATE, MAKELONG(UIS_SET, UISF_HIDEFOCUS), 0);`.

Comment: I tried. both were not working

Comment: Use a toolbar instead.